# What is the benefit of using Sections and Articles over tables in an MVC view?

Tags: html, .net-core

I am looking at an MVC view, which looks like this:

```
<div class="orders">
    <partial name="_Header" model="headerList"/>

    <div class="container">
        <article class="orders-titles row">
            <section class="orders-title col-2">Order number</section>
            <section class="orders-title col-4">Date</section>
            <section class="orders-title col-2">Total</section>
            <section class="orders-title col-2">Status</section>
            <section class="orders-title col-2"></section>
        </article>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <article class="orders-items row">
                    <section class="orders-item col-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNumber)</section>
                    <section class="orders-item col-4">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</section>
                    <section class="orders-item col-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</section>
                    <section class="orders-item col-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</section>
                    <section class="orders-item col-1">
                        <a class="orders-link" asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-orderId="@item.OrderNumber">Detail</a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="orders-item col-1">
                        @if (item.Status.ToLower() == "submitted")
                        {
                            <a class="orders-link" asp-controller="Order" asp-action="cancel" asp-route-orderId="@item.OrderNumber">Cancel</a>
                        }
                    </section>
                </article>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I have seen lots of other examples similar to this.  I would normally use a table for this using the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

Therefore I believe I am missing something fundamental.  I believe there will be tradeoffs using both approaches.  What are the benefits and limitations of using articles and sections instead of tables?

I have spent hours Googling this and I have found lots of information explaining what Sections and articles are e.g. here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp and here: [Should <sections> have <articles> or should <articles> have <sections>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527378/should-sections-have-articles-or-should-articles-have-sections).  However, I have not found anything, which explains when I should use them (in a MVC View context).

What is the benefit of using articles and sections over tables?

**Update**

I took this from a price comparison website:

[image]

Would you expect the data in the above image to be structured in a table? I.e. with six columns.  It appears to be structured as divs.

Answer (score 1):

The tools you use to generate HTML are irrelevant (so the fact you are using ASP.NET MVP views is beside the point).

HTML is a semantic markup language. It is consumed by visual browsers to render a display people can read with their eyes. It is consumed by screen readers to convey information aurally. It is consumed by search engines to help people find content. It is consumed by other data processing tools for a variety of purpose.

The semantics are there to describe what the content *is* and tools use that information for all sorts of purposes.

Consequently, the elements you use should be chosen to best reflect the semantics of the content so that tools can make the best use of that data.

In your example, your content doesn't look remotely like a series of articles divided into sections, so — *for the content in the question* — using those elements would be wrong and would have only drawbacks.

If you have *tabular data* then **use a table**.

Only use article and section elements when your content has articles and sections.

Comment: this approach appears to be recommended by Microsoft in one of their sample apps: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Web/WebMVC/Views/Order/Index.cshtml.  Do you know why they would recommend this?

Comment: @w0051977 — The only reason I can think of is that they heard the new elements were great and didn't consider that their greatness only applies when used correctly (and then the peer review process failed)

Comment: Thank you.  Would you expect the code in the view in the hyperlink to be a table (<thead> and <tbody>) rather than sections and articles?

Comment: Yes, I would. Tabular data should be expressed in tables.

Comment: Can you finally provide an example of data that would be article and section (forum and forum entry maybe?).

Comment: Finally, what about divs? I notice that price comparison website appear to use divs to display tabular data (search results)? Surely that is tabular data? +1 for the hyperlinks.

Comment: Div is a generic block element. Use it when you need a block element and no element exists with the correct semantics. Don't use it as a substitute for table/tr//td/th/etc when you have tabular data.

Comment: Could you answer the question in my edit before I accept? Thanks again.

Comment: Do you think I should be asking another separate question for the above comment?